# Load Rails 3 test fixtures into development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I have a nice set of fixtures that I use for testing. When a request test fails it is handy to run the app interactively with the test fixtures loaded. But if I run the full server with -e test I get all kinds of crazy errors, probably having to do with the pipeline.

-- edit --

When I visit the home page I get this in the browser:

[image]

I say it's crazy, because I don't understand it :) In particular, I am using twitter-bootstrap and I am unclear about sass/scss/css work with Twitter Bootstrap + Rails so it's highly likely that I have some detail wrong in how I am using them together (or that the gem twitter-bootstrap-rails has some bug.)

Comment: Typically, asset pipeline is not used for a test environment.  So, um, *what* crazy errors?

Comment: @tharrison I added a screenshot showing the 'crazy' error to the OP. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, much better question :-).

The `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem uses LESS, which is similar to SASS in what it does, but *not* the same.  SASS is the default for Rails, and a good choice.  If you want to use SASS, (and based on the error, it appears you are), then use the [Bootstrap SASS gem instead, linked here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass).  It may be possible to use both LESS and SASS together, but that seems like a Bad Idea to me.

Check out [Ryan Bates' excellent RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) which covers using Twitter Bootstrap in Rails.  It covers both alternatives.  And then fork over the $9 to get Pro access to his continued RailsCast with more details.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. And yes, my fork has been pointed in his direction for a while now :)